# Is it possible to send out an outlook delayed email without keeping the application running?

Tags: email, outlook, send, outlook-2010

I am using outlook 2012 and was wondering if the above is possible. So even though my computer is off, the email should still send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If Outlook is not running, it can't send an email.

Comment: I knew it sounded illogical but i thought there might have been a cool trick somewhere